# Accesing TabLayout's Fragment within the activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout, fragment-backstack

I'm trying to access the fragment's tag within the activity to perform some logic in that particular fragment by triggering one method(refreshData).Since the fragment comes under Tablayout, i'm fully stuck on how to access the fragment under my activity.
The following is the code snippet:

```
   private void updateFragment(Intent intent){
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        for (int i = 0; i < manager.getBackStackEntryCount(); i++) {
            if (MyFragment.class.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(manager.getBackStackEntryAt(i).getName())) {
                MyFragment currentFragment = (MyFragment)manager.findFragmentByTag(manager.getBackStackEntryAt(i).getName());
                currentFragment.refreshData(intent);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

The following way I'm creating two fragment under TabLayout

```
 @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    MyFragment newsFragment = new MyFragment();

                    return newsFragment;

                case 1:
                    return new MySecondFragment();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create only one object of each fragments, like

```
MyFragemnt newsFragment;
MySecondFragment secondFragemnt;
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
   switch (position) {
     case 0:
       if(newsFragment == null)
           newsFragment = new MyFragment();
       return newsFragment;
     case 1:
       if(secondFragemnt== null)
           secondFragemnt= new MySecondFragment();
       return secondFragemnt;
      }
    return null;
}
```

Then based on position of your adapter, you can access the `refreshData()` of those fragment.

```
Fragment activeFragment = adapter.getItem(pos);
if(pos == 0)
    ((MyFragment)activeFragment).refreshData(...);
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to favor the `ArrayList` approach for storing the `Fragment` references.  The key to this working is `instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)`. This is probably the most important method in the `PagerAdapter` as it is responsible for re-attaching the fragments on a configuration change.  It will only call `getItem(int position)` if it does not find a fragment in memory.  By implementing this method and having it put the re-attached fragments into the `ArrayList` you will have the same fragments in the list after a configuration change.

```
public class SomePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>(4);

        public SomePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    return FirstFragment.newInstance();
                case 1:
                    return SecondFragment.newInstance();;
                default:
                    return new Fragment();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
            fragments.add(fragment);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        public ArrayList<Fragment> getFragments() {
            return fragments;
        }
    }
```

You can use the above code like this:

```
if(pagerAdapter.getFragments.get(whateverPosition) instanceof FirstFragment {
      ((FirstFragment)pagerAdapter.getFragments().get(whateverPosition)).refreshData(intent);
}
```

The check for `instanceof` is not really needed if you are always sure of what you are accessing, I just prefer to be sure that what I am accessing is what I expect.

The other answer will work until a configuration change. After that you will find yourself referencing an entirely new fragment which may not be what you expected to happen.

Also keep in mind, it is best practice to instantiate a `Fragment` with the `newInstance` static method due to the way the System uses the consructors of a `Fragment`. You can pass anything you want through `newInstance()` which you cannot do with a constructor.